# How to get number of queued jobs in IronMQ using Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-5.1, ironmq

Implementing queues & jobs in Laravel 5.1 in my project using [IronMQ](https://github.com/iron-io/iron_mq_php), I can now send jobs to the IronMQ queue like you see in image bellow :

[image]

What I want now is to get the current number of messages in queue (number in red box) in the handle function in my job, find job code bellow :

```
class GetWords extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue{
use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;


    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     */
    public function __construct(Url $url)
    {
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //getting the name of queue
        dd($this->job->getName()); //return 'words'

        $currentNumberMsgsInQueue = ?????; //i can't find how

        //Condition
        if($currentNumberMsgsInQueue == 10){
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

**Question is :** How to get number of queued jobs (messages) in IronMQ queue using Laravel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of searching I found the answer, there's no `method/function` in **Laravel 5.1** that can give us the number of queued jobs in **IronMQ**.

But against **[IronMQ On-Premise API Reference](http://dev.iron.io/mq/3/reference/api/)** give us a solution, it's a **[REST/HTTP API](http://dev.iron.io/mq/reference/api/#endpoints)** that allow us to query different requests using **javascript** to set/get all what we want from/to queue (Get Queue, Update Queue, List Queues ...) and from/to messages in every queue (Get Message by Id, Get all Messages, Clear Messages ...).

> [Base URL](http://dev.iron.io/mq/reference/api/#base_url) :
>
> ***https://{Host}/{API Version}/projects/{Project_ID}/queues/{Queue_Name}/messages/webhook?oauth={Token}***

Example, if we want the number of messages in queue, we have just to **[Get Queue Info](http://dev.iron.io/mq/3/reference/api/#get-queue)** and peek the `size` from result.

```
GET /queues/{Queue Name}
```

---

**A Practical Example :**

You can find your first base link inside the concerned queue in your project under **Webhook URL** case (see picture bellow) :

[image]

**JS code :**

```
//To get queue info we have url : GET /queues/{Queue Name}
var url = "https://{Host}/{API Version}/projects/{Project_ID}/queues/{Queue_Name}?oauth={Token}";

//Using ajax $.get
$.get( url ,
function( result ) {
     alert( "Queue size is :" + result["queue"]["size"]);
});
```

**Result :**

```
{
  "queue": {
    "project_id": 123,
    "name": "my_queue",
    "size": 0,
    "total_messages": 0,
    "message_timeout": 60,
    "message_expiration": 604800,
    "type": "pull/unicast/multicast",
    "push": {
      "subscribers": [
        {
          "name": "subscriber_name",
          "url": "http://mysterious-brook-1807.herokuapp.com/ironmq_push_1",
          "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        }
      ],
      "retries": 3,
      "retries_delay": 60,
      "error_queue": "error_queue_name",
      "rate_limit": 10
    }
  }
}
```